# How did Gauss make use of Hopf link and Whitehead link??

Tags: reference-request, knot-theory

The author of the book "Knots, Links, Braids and 3-Manifolds: An Introduction to the New Invariants in Low-Dimensional Topology" states (on page 6) the the Hopf link and Whitehead link were known long ago "and used **in particular** by Gauss". This sentence really eroused my curiosity - how did Gauss make use of these two links? and where does it appear in his Nachlass?

Comment: It's the Gauss electromagnetic linking coefficient, see [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=lRLwUP8LLLcC&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=the+the+Hopf+link+and+Whitehead+link+were+known+long+ago+and+used+in+particular+by+Gauss&source=bl&ots=X5Zla3OF7x&sig=CozhyUxwGFu8PLFJmH-uGxx2lzA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizraSh55vYAhVFLFAKHYgpAigQ6AEINzAC#v=onepage&q=the%20the%20Hopf%20link%20and%20Whitehead%20link%20were%20known%20long%20ago%20and%20used%20in%20particular%20by%20Gauss&f=false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find "GAUSS’ LINKING NUMBER REVISITED" helpful http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/ricca.pdf

Excerpt: 
"The concept of linking number was introduced by Carl Friedrich Gauss in a brief
note on a page of his personal diary — a kind of logbook of his most important
discoveries ([5, p. 19]) — dated January 22, 1833 (see Fig. 1(a) and the English
translation in Fig. 1(b))."

The aforementioned figures, included in the paper, show the notes (in German)

Comment: I know this article; is that all about? are you sure that this is the poet's (author of the book) intention? i ask because it's not a particular use of those two links - it's just a mathematical piece related to them.